# Sublime Text doesn't recognize Python modules that are already installed since I installed Anaconda

Tags: python, playsound

maybe the compiler's path to the installed modules is incorrect or something like that

Numpy is not working, librosa and playsound as well although I checked on terminal and saw that the location of these two of them are anaconda3 folder somewhere

update: restarted IDE when I ran it again I received a massage to download PyObjC, anyone knows the connection to the problem I've had?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I believe it's a pretty clear and insightful question (who knows what's the connection between the problem I had to downloading PyObjC?)